# Authenticating with OAuth for Instagram without requiring a pop-up window

Tags: php, curl, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to use OAuth for Instagram to authenticate, planning to use PHP and cURL. The first step is retrieving a "code" e.g:

`fd7d5f6cde6c47e4a86ba28b22ac4583`

I've worked with the Twitter API before and it works in a similar way. I exchange the code for an `access_token` and then I can authenticate.

The issue is that the way to authenticate is to hit a button on a window that says "I give permission". Here is that window:

[image]

**My question : is there a way to do this without requiring hitting this URL?**

For example, is there a way for me to automate this process using my script? When I worked with Twitter, I was able to use cURL to go to this link and pass the authentication, to then retrieve this code.

This is part of a project that will *only be used by me* essentially to retrieve my own recent instagrams. I don't want visitors to my site to be presented with having to hit "authorise" every time they turn up.

At the moment I'm simply doing this, is there anything I can add to the URL to automatically authorise?

```
$auth_request_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='.$client_id.'&redirect_uri='.$redirect_url .'&response_type=code';
/* Send user to authorisation */
header("Location: ".$auth_request_url);
```

Below is an example of the code **that works** but only **once**:

```
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
    $access_token_parameters = array(
        'client_id'                =>     $client_id,
        'client_secret'            =>     $client_secret,
        'grant_type'               =>     'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri'             =>     $redirect_url,
        'code'                     =>     $code
    );

$curl = curl_init($url);    // we init curl by passing the url
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);   // to send a POST request
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$access_token_parameters);   // indicate the data to send
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   // to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
    $result = curl_exec($curl);   // to perform the curl session
    curl_close($curl);   // to close the curl session

    $arr = json_decode($result,true);
```

I got the `$code` from the end of the URL manually. But it expires after one use. So I need to work out how to run and retrieve the `$code` each time I want to execute the script.

Comment: You should be able to retrieve your own Instagrams in PHP without any JavaScript pop-ups on the client side. That will require an Instagram API secret, which should just work without seeing this dialogue box. This looks like you are asking the user for authorisation to access _their_ account, which is something very different.

Comment: @halfer that is what I was expecting. Can you link to where in the docu it says I can use the key and secret to auth? I haven't found any mention of it.

Comment: Are you using a library? There are a [few GitHub results here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=instagram+api+php) that might be worth a go. (I can't say definitively, as I've not used Instagram or its API).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approval should only be required the first time that your client asks a user for it and there's no way to avoid that. You're obtaining information from an end user and it would be a huge security hole if clients could get that information or permissions from users without requiring their explicit approval at least once. But after the first time, consent should be stored and reused for your client.

Comment: What I don't understand is how I could even make this work. This is my own site, so even if i get this up and running, every time someone comes to my site they are going to be asked to log in to my instagram. How does that work? They won't be able to.

Comment: if you only want to access *your* instagram data from your app, you should go through the "code" flow out-of-band and store the access token in the backend for your app; hopefully instagram will also provide a refresh token so that the app can renew the access token autonomously

Comment: That's what I've done. I retrieved the code from the URL and have then sent it using cURL. I was able to retrieve the access_token just fine. Probably is, once that code is used up it can't be used again. So I have to regenerate a code every time I want to perform the call. So I need to automate the process of retrieving the code.

Comment: I have updated OP to show code I have tried. Works once. I need to retrieve a new `$code` every time. That's what I can't understand.

Comment: yes, you can use the `code` only once, that's how it was designed; but you can use the access token for a longer period of time across multiple API calls; I'm not sure what Instagram's expiry policy is wrt. access tokens, but if they'd provide a refresh token as well, you could use that to refresh the access token without requiring your manual intervention again

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the explanation. I'll use the access code I have retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind old, but I think:

After `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id='.$client_id.'&redirect_uri='.$redirect_url .'&response_type=code';`

it will redirect to your `$redirect_url/?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXX`

So you can retrieve code by `$code = $_GET['code']`